# how to open folder in GUI in windows command?

Tags: windows, cmd

I know that I can open a GUI(Graphical User Interface) folder in MacOS with the command "open .",

but how can I do this in windows?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I got it!

The answer is to write "start xxx"

PS. xxx is the name of the folder.

Comment: Safer, because of spaces/special characters, is ```Start "" "absolute or relative folder name"```